# Redirection not happening in asp.net mvc controller action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
Public class ItemController : Controller 
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("Index");
    }

    public ActionResult ItemDescription()
    {
        return  View("ItemIndex");
    }
}
```

Now there are two Views in Item Folder

View1 :Index

View2 : ItemIndex

ItemIndex

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ItemIndex";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>ItemIndex</h2>
<input type="button" value="Next"  onclick="redirecttodetails()" />
<script type="text/javascript">
     function redirecttodetails() 
     {
         $.ajax({
              url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Item")',
              type: 'POST'
         });
     }
</script>
```

Now the issue is I have a button in my ItemIndex view, by clicking on the view I want to redirect to Index view which is not happening.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `window.location.href`. `$.ajax` will not redirect you.

```
 function redirecttodetails() 
 {
     window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Item")';
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ajax won't redirect you to a new page.  Change it to this:

```
 function redirecttodetails() 
 {
     window.location.href =  '@Url.Action("Index", "Item")';
 }
```

Comment: Thanks the solution is working . BUt i am not able to correct both answers .Looks like he other guy answered 1 min earlier than you .Anyway thanks much